# How to properly implement a CausalImpact on a time series

Tags: time-series

I have a time series with the percentage of the subscriber based on the total users in my platform. Let's say I did an event that could, potentially, affected the figures. I could run a [CausalImpact](https://google.github.io/CausalImpact/CausalImpact.html) from Google Github and check the exact effect.

However, my question is. Should I apply the algorithm to the raw data of the time series? Or it would be better if I do some kind of decomposition before?